# background gps location in react native

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, gps

I want to track my location when app is background state, i can track my location when it foreground, but i want to track even in background also, i need to pass the my gps location to the my server, for that one i used some module like :
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-mauron85-background-geolocation
but it is not showing any location like that,

even i checked the example also for this one but i didn't got the correct response for it,

Here is the link for example:
https://github.com/mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation-example

when i run this example and click on play button it is showing an error alert and undefined,

can any one give me suggestions that how to resolve this error.

Any help much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Changes to location tracking in iOS 11**

iOS 11 also makes some major changes to existing APIs. One of the affected areas is location tracking. **If your app only uses location while the app is in the foreground**, as most apps do, you might not have to change anything at all; however, if it’s one of those apps that continuously track user’s location throughout the day, you should probably book some time this summer for making some changes in how you do the tracking and testing possible usage scenarios.

follow this link: https://mackuba.eu/2017/07/13/changes-to-location-tracking-in-ios-11/

Hope will helpful to you!!